# Как не потерять исключения из другого потока

Tags: c#, wpf, исключения, task

Имеется фрагмент кода:
**Dataflow**:

```
 var ActionBlock = TransformBlock<ActionParams, string>(async n =>
     try
     {
         Task.Run(n.func);         
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         if (MessageBoxResult.Yes == ExceptionMessageBase(e.Message, a)) { //бла бл }
     }
 )};
```

То, что в него посылается:

```
public static void Auth()
{                    
    Api ap = new Api(); 
    AuthPool.Add(() =>
    {
         ap.Authorize(_aap); 
    }, new ActionParams());
}
```

Add:

```
    public void Add(Action func, PMData data, string name = null)
    {
        ActionParams _pack = new ActionParams();
        _pack.TargetAction = func;
        _pack.ActionName = name;
        _pack.Data = data;
        ActionBlock.Post(_pack);

    }
```

Но обработка исключения возникшее `n.func` не срабатывает. Точнее вызов исключения внутри функции срабатывает и программа падает. 
Если `n.func` запускать без `Task` то исключение перехватывается отлично.
Но как отловить исключения возникшее в потоке где выполняется функция и обработать во внешнем коде?

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно

```
await Task.Run(n.func);
```

Это доставит исключение в блок try/catch.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37331/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd-------).

Answer (score 1):

Решение вышло примерно такое:

```
 var ActionBlock = TransformBlock<ActionParams, string>(async n =>
     try
     {
         await Task.Run(()=> 
         { 
            try { n.func(); }
            catch (Exception e) { throw new Exception(e.Message, e.innerException); } 
         });         
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         if (MessageBoxResult.Yes == ExceptionMessageBase(e.Message, a)) { //бла бл }
     }
)};
```

Comment: Подождите, а зачем вам ловить исключение, чтобы сразу его тут же снова бросить?

Comment: Почему не просто `await Task.Run(() => n.func());`? Должно быть в точности то же самое.

Comment: @VladD, увы почему то в моем случае 'Task' проглатывал. Вроде проверил все что мог и ничего необычного в вызываемом коде не было. А это решение как раз на такие случаи. Конечно может и быдловато выглядит, но вполне рабоче.

Comment: Хм, очень странно. Может быть, у вас есть тип `Exception` в другом неймспейсе?

Comment: @VladD , ну исключение генерируется в используемом API и генерирует свое собственное исключение, а у него понятное дело свои неймспэйсы.

Comment: Всё ещё непонятно. А если вы вместо `throw new Exception(e.Message, e.innerException);` напишете просто `throw;`, что произойдёт?

Comment: @VladD на этом `throw` он останавливается и вызывает исключение, не передавая его во внешний код.

Comment: Очень странно. Покажите скриншот, а? Может, там что-то полезное будет.

Comment: @VladD [Скриншот исключения](https://pp.vk.me/c633930/v633930173/19441/zc_0apAxlGY.jpg) , ничего особого

Comment: Окей. Давайте тогда в качестве шаманских танцев с бубном вместо внешнего `catch (Exception e)` напишем `catch (System.Exception e)`. И временно оставим `throw;`.

Comment: @VladD Ситуация идентичная

Comment: Ну вот смотрите. Я моделирую вашу ситуацию тут: http://ideone.com/JS33dn, и всё происходит нормально. Не понимаю, где отличие вашего случая от моего примера.

Comment: Может, вы не приводите какую-то важную часть кода?

Comment: Ещё идиотский вопрос: какая у вас версия .NET? :)

Comment: @VladD , незнаю, может это какая-то "Особенность" `Dataflow`, ибо больше ничего важного и не используется. Версия `4.5`

Comment: Смотрите. Дело в том, что исключение вовсе не покидает вашу лямбда-функцию, поэтому Dataflow не участвует в проблеме.